# Как перехватить get запрос в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

При отрисовке страницы происходит несколько get запросов на подгрузку изображений.

```
GET: mysite.loc/cat/page1.html
GET: mysite.loc/cat/images/img1.jpg
GET: mysite.loc/cat/images/img2.jpg
...
```

Раньше, наличие запросов на изображение определялось просто - через *apache mod_rewrite*.  При определении запроса на изображение запускался скрипт подменяющий заголовки на нужные.
Т.е. в .htaccess стояло правило:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+)/(.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))$ /mysript.php?imgpath=$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Переписывая скрипт как плагин для WP, столкнулся с проблемой того, что движок ничего не хранит в глобальном $_GET.  По сути, само точное значение *imgpath* меня не интересует, а необходимо знать о его существовании(либо отсутствии), дабы подставить заголовки в нужный момент.

Пробовал использовать встроенную в wp api функцию *add_rewrite_tag()*, но она не помогла.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: @Visman А как это поможет?, это же выводит информацию о запросе который вызывает скрипт т.е. `GET: mysite.loc/cat/page1.html`

Answer (score 1):

`get_query_var` эта функция позволяет вытащить гет параметр

Так регистрируются параметры

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "my_var";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var